# Translate a PHP cURL to a bash cURL call

Tags: php, json, bash, curl, scripting

I have this PHP code that makes a curl call:

```
  $postData['api_user'] = 'username';
   $postData['api_key'] = 'password!';

$ch = curl_init('https://api.example.com/send.json');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
```

I know that in order to make a curl call with json in bash I have to do this:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://hostname/resource
```

But I'm confused in how I can transfer all my php code to bash curl call, what I mean is for example what would be the equivalent of curl_setopt(), and to pass the credentials as an array like I did with http_build_query()

Comment: Why don't you leave it as PHP and use command line PHP to run it?

Comment: Because I want to know how I can run a curl call using those options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cURL to POST your data as JSON.

```
curl -i \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X POST --data '{"api_user": "username", "api_key":"password!"}' \
--insecure \
https://api.example.com/send.json
```

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` equals `-k, --insecure`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData))
```

equals `-X POST --data ...`

`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`... hmm, i don't know ,)

Comment: and inside POST --data I can pass an array of options besides the api user and key correct?

Comment: Yes, `--data` equals POSTFIELDS. Basically the data you would send from a browser after filling a form and pressing submit. You might also take a look at the manpage for cURL - https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html - just search for "--data".

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty helpful

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` has no CLI equivalent as it [prevents curl output](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) from going to stdout rather than being the return value of PHP's `curl_exec`. At the command line all output goes to stdout/stderr.

Comment: For some reason I execute my php file http://fixee.org/paste/0riwa2h/ and it gets success and when I execute that bash script I get a denied error, do you know by any chance if I'm missing something? I see the same. Thank you very much.

Comment: And this is what I came up with based on your code: http://fixee.org/paste/h01nphr/ for me it looks right.

Comment: It could be that the special char `@` needs to be escaped or url-encoded. `@ = %40` Not sure. You could also try using `--data-raw` instead of `--data` .. https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-raw

Answer (score 0):

`-d` is the `curl` flag to send `POST` data, but you'll have to format it as a JSON string:

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "api_user": "username", "api_key": "password" }' https://api.example.com/send.json
```

And now with those extra options (look them up in the [curl man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) page):

```sh
curl -X POST -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "api_user": "username", "api_key": "password" }' https://api.example.com/send.json
```

As a much friendlier alternative to `curl` I recommend checking out [httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie). Here's what your call would look like with `httpie`:

```sh
http --verify=no https://api.example.com/send.json api_user=username api_key=password
```